# FFmpeg -> JSMpeg Websocket Closes Repeatedly

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg, rtmp

I'm trying to create a fairly simple streaming server/site.  Here's the current flow:

- OBS streams to an RTMP URL
- Nginx accepts the RTMP stream and uses `exec-push` to have FFmpeg pick up the stream and transcode it
- FFmpeg transcodes the stream and outputs it to a JSMpeg application, which displays the stream on a webpage.

When I have my `exec_push` statement as follows, everything seems to work perfectly, except the browser says `Possible garbage data. Skipping.` on every frame it receives:

```
exec_push /usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/$app/$name -f mpeg1video  http://localhost:8080/supersecret;
```

This behavior is understandable, because JSMpeg must receive MPEG-TS data, not MPEG1 data.  It sees the MPEG1 frames and thinks they're garbage.

So through some online research, I found this:

```
exec_push /usr/bin/ffmpeg -re -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/$app/$name -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts http://localhost:8080/supersecret;
```

Supposedly, this is supposed to transcode my RTMP stream into an MPEG-TS format, which should be compatible with JSMpeg.

However, with the second version of the command, my FFmpeg -> JSMpeg stream keeps connecting and disconnecting, connecting and disconnecting, and so on.  This behavior is observed in terminal:

```
Stream Connected: ::1:40208
close
Stream Connected: ::1:40212
close
Stream Connected: ::1:40216
close
Stream Connected: ::1:40220
close
Stream Connected: ::1:40224
close
...
```

What would cause this?  I am pretty certain the issue is in my `exec_push` command.  OBS is perfectly content, which tells me that the stream is making it to the server, and if I do a `push`, I can do a test push to Ustream just fine, which tells me that Nginx is at least processing the stream with some reasonable degree of success.

---

*Disclaimer: I have no idea what I'm talking about.  Everything I know about FFmpeg and JSMpeg/Node is from snippets of code that I found online.*

Comment: With ` -c:v copy -c:a copy` there's no transcoding, only stream passthrough. Unless you know the input codecs can be correctly muxed by ffmpeg into mpeg-ts, I would drop these and check.

Comment: @Mulvya Thank you, so so so so much.  The signal is garbled, but the picture is coming through.  I think I can deal with it from here.

Comment: Hey can you share how you fixed the garbled signal?

Comment: @ThomasHarris I wish!  Lol.  I ended up abandoning the project before I ever got it fully working.  If I ever pick it back up again and get it fully working, I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer credit goes to @Mulvya.

In the second `exec_push` command, the `-c:v copy -c:a copy` should not be there.  **By using that, there isn't any transcoding going on-- it's just a stream passthrough.**

Removing the `-c:v copy -c:a copy` from the command and restarting Nginx yields a successful stream.